# toolbar back button problem

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I would like to add a toolbar to a UIWebView that resembles Safari's toolbar. I just can't find the 'back button' . There is only 'forward button' - which is actually 'play'. Help!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a custom button they created for the Safari app.